# RFID IC (MFRC522) with 50-Ohm antenna (taoglas fxr.01.A)

Tags: antenna, rfid, mfrc522

I am trying to make the MFRC522 (https://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MFRC522.pdf) to work with a taoglas 50-Ohm antenna (http://taoglas.com/images/product_images/original_images/FXR.01.07.0100C.A.pdf)

To start I based my schematic and layout in the arduino RFID board but the problem here is that this board uses a PCB antenna and the circuit is composed with EM filter and impedance matching.

I think that as I am using a 50-Ohm antenna, I don´t need to build the impedance matching part, but the problem is that I can´t find a place I can get a circuit for MFRC522 with a 50-Ohm antenna.

I appreciate all the help!

Thanks!

EDIT:

My question is what is the circuit I need to build between the MFRC522 and the Antenna. And what is the values of the components.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the circuit I need to build between the mrfc522 and the antenna.

And the values of the components

Thank!

Comment: Please edit your question, to include the question.

Answer (score 5):

After a long night I figured out what to do.

This PDF, [Design of MF RC500 Matching Circuits and Antennas](http://read.pudn.com/downloads153/doc/670844/Design_of_MF_RC500_Matching_circuits_and_Antennas.pdf) ([alternative source](http://read.pudn.com/downloads115/ebook/486162/RC522%E5%BC%80%E5%8F%91%E5%A5%97%E4%BB%B6/%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3/0495101.pdf)), has a detailed info about how to implement what I wanted.

This is the image of the circuit I implemented, just needed to change some values of caps, but all near to the ones in the image. Worked perfectly.

[image: Values for the EMC- Filter and Receiving Circuit]
[image: Values for the impedance transformation]
[image: 50 Ω Short Range solution: 50 Ω impedance transformation using one driver stage]